# Can we show that $e^{-1/x^2}$ cannot be extended to a holomorphic function in a neighbourhood of the reals using the identity theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I want to show that the following real valued function cannot be extended to a holomorphic complex function in a neighbourhood of $R$ :
[image]

I am not allowed to use singularities and poles or the Laurent series as those have not been introduced yet, but I can use the identity theorem and I wonder if the application here is correct. I have shown that the real valued derivative of the real valued function at 0 is 0 for all orders. Now if we had an extension to a holomorphic function, then the partial derivative $f_x^{(n)}$ is also 0 at 0 for all $n$. The partial derivative with respect to the reals of a holomorphic function is just the complex derivative, and by one of the corollary of the identity theorem. if all higher order derivatives is $0$ at a point, then the function is 0 on the entire domain which is a contradiction since $e^{-1/x^2}$ is not identically 0 everywhere.

Is this argument valid?

Comment: It's much easier than this, you can just use the identity theorem on $(-\infty, 0)$.

Comment: What happens to the power series expansion around $0$?